# Supplied objective function must return a scalar value

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, scalar, objective-function

I am trying to code a ML algorithm in Matlab. These are my different functions:

sigmoid.m:

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
g = zeros(size(z));
g = 1 ./ (1+exp(z));
```

costFunction.m

```
function [J, grad ] = costFunction(theta, X, y)

m = length(y); % number of training examples
z = -X * theta;
g = sigmoid(z);
J = 1/m * ((-y * log(g)') - ((1 - y) * log(1 - g)'));

grad = zeros(size(theta'));
grad = (1/m) * (X' * (g - y));
```

ex2.m (This is the main file of my project and I put the relative lines I get this error message)

```
options = optimset('GradObj', 'on', 'MaxIter', 400);

[theta, cost] = ...
    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)), initial_theta, options);
```

The error message:

> Error using fminunc (line 348) Supplied objective function must return
>   a scalar value.
>
> Error in ex2 (line 97)    fminunc(@(t)(costFunction(t, X, y)),
>   initial_theta, options);

I don't know is there enough information above or not? If not, let me know to add extra information.

Comment: The error is saying that the objective function (here that's `costFunction()`) needs to return a single value (i.e. a scalar value), not an array or matrix. You don't show what `X` and `y` are, nor your `initial_theta`, so it's hard to say what's getting returned by the function since we don't know what's being passed in. It would be helpful if you gave a [mcve]

Comment: Your cost function is returning both `J` and `grad`, so it is returning a vector and not the scalar value `fminunc` expects. I can't remember my neural network maths very well, but I think you need to minimise `J`, so you should edit `costFunction.m` to return only this.

Comment: @Justin: `X is a 100*1 matrix` , `y is a 100*1 matrix, `initial_theta is a 3*1 matrix`, 
 ` g is a 100*1 matrix` , `J is a 100*100 matrix` and `grad is a 3*1 matrix`.

Comment: @RPM: This is an assignment on coursera and costfunction's return values are predefined! So you mean they did mistake in creating this exercise?

Comment: @RPM: Maybe I should do the multiplication in `J` , in reverse side? At this time I do multiplying `y = 100*1` to `transpose of log(g) that is a 1*1001 and causes a `100*100 matrix J`. If I transpose `y` instead of `log(g)` I will get a `1*1` matrix!

Comment: @RPM, I did what I said above and seems the problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin: Thank you! I got the idea from your comment and changed my `J` as I wrote above and seems the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the following line of code:

```
J = 1/m * ((-y * log(g)') - ((1 - y) * log(1 - g)'));
```

To the following line of code:

```
J = 1/m * (((-y)' * log(g)) - ((1 - y)' * log(1 - g)));
```

And problem solved!
The `y` and `g` were `100*1` matrices and with previous code I had `J=100*100` matrix, but with new code I have `J=1*1` matrix or scalar number and problem solved!